# Can SVG <use xlink> be used in a CSS background-image?

Tags: html, css, svg

Here we can see that **SVGs** can be used in **CSS background images**.

```
.icon {
   background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="16" viewBox="0 0 64 16"> <circle fill="blue" cx="8" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="red" cx="24" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="yellow" cx="40" cy="8" r="8"/> <circle fill="green" cx="56" cy="8" r="8"/> </svg>');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: auto 100%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

But can `<svg><use xlink:href="svg.svg#mySVG"></use></svg>` be implemented? It is **invalid CSS** for me, but I might just be doing something wrong.

Comment: images must be complete in a single file so the `<use>` reference would have to be internal to the image and not to an external file as you have it.

Answer (score 2):

As @Robert Longson already commented:
**No, you can't access external `<use>` references in images**

This applies to:

- css `background-image`
- html `<img>` elements
- svg `<image>` elements
- css pseudo elements using Data URLs within `content` property

From mdn web docs: [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)

> Note: Data URLs are treated as unique opaque origins by modern
> browsers, rather than inheriting the origin of the settings object
> responsible for the navigation.

Data URLs can't contain external file references – they will be omitted.

So you can only render self contained elements:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="64" height="16" viewBox="0 0 64 16">
  <defs>
    <circle id="circle" cx="8" cy="8" r="8" />
  </defs>
  <use href="#circle" fill="blue" />
  <use x="16" href="#circle" fill="red" />
  <use x="32" href="#circle" fill="yellow" />
  <use x="48" href="#circle" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Converted to

```
.icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='64' height='16' viewBox='0 0 64 16'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Ccircle id='circle' cx='8' cy='8' r='8' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cuse href='%23circle' fill='blue' /%3E%3Cuse x='16' href='%23circle' fill='red' /%3E%3Cuse x='32' href='%23circle' fill='yellow' /%3E%3Cuse x='48' href='%23circle' fill='green' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 1em;
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

would work. However, you won't be able to select or style elements as you can with inlined svgs.

```css
.icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='64' height='16' viewBox='0 0 64 16'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Ccircle id='circle' cx='8' cy='8' r='8' /%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cuse href='%23circle' fill='blue' /%3E%3Cuse x='16' href='%23circle' fill='red' /%3E%3Cuse x='32' href='%23circle' fill='yellow' /%3E%3Cuse x='48' href='%23circle' fill='green' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tag **`<use>`** with attribute **`xlink:href`** is **deprecated**
according to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use)
*

> Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended. Though some
> browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from
> the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or
> may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and
> update existing code if possible; see the compatibility table at the
> bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature
> may cease to work at any time.

- 

Comment: Yes `xlink:href` is classified as deprecated but **it's still used and also required by a lot of applications (like graphic editors, or pdf converters)**. [Browser Support is also complete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use#browser_compatibility). So it **rarely the real cause of referencing problems.**

Answer (score -1):

that's right, you can use SVG into CSS background-image.

```css
.img{
  background-image: url('background-image: url( "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 600 200'%3E%3Cpath d='M10 10h123v123H10z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" );
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: @M Naufal Helmi: Sorry, but the OP's answer was about **external file references** within a Data-URL and not about whether they work for `background-images`. Besides, your code snippet has errors (you've repeated 'background-image' in 'url()').

Comment: ohh im sorry for about that sir, i replace my code background-image to snippet. im newbie actually and i want to help for this problem. forgive me about my problem sir

Answer (score -2):

This will be passed in W3C validator and A-checker without any errors. Also, the url of the CSS class won't be an issue as we are specifyig a path to CSS, and until it is valid or correct, the browser will render it.